# Does happen-before in Java new memory model also apply to the member of a object which is declared as volatile?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model, happens-before

In the new Java memory model, any write to a variable is guaranteed to be completed before the next thread read it.

I wonder if this is also the case for variables that are member of this object.

for java memory model:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html

E.g.

```
public class VolatileTest {
    private volatile Map<String, Function> functionMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Function getFunction(String key) {
        Function function = this.functionMap.get(key);

        if (function == null) {
            //Is this guaranteed to be fully constructed? I don't think so.
            function = new Function(key);

            this.functionMap.put(key, function);
        }

        return function;
    }
}
```

Like above code, even by making `functionMap` volatile, it still doesn't guarantee the function object will be fully constructed before this method return.

Is my thinking right?

Also just for this topic, I'd like you guys to check is my thinking right for the following:

Like the below any write to the `functionMap` is guaranteed to be completed before changing the reference of `functionMap`, right? No matter how long the `initializeMap` methods take, the other thread will either see a null `functionMap` or a fully initialized `functionMap`?

```
public Map<String,Function> getFunctionMap (){
    Map<String, Function> tempMap = new HashMap<>();

    initalizeMap(tempMap); //fill in values

    // Above operation is guaranteed to be completed
    //   before changing the reference of this variable.
    this.functionMap = tempMap;

    // So here you will either see a null or a fully initialized map.
    // Is my understanding right?
    return this.functionMap;
}
```

**Just to clarify above, above two examples are all in multi-thread environment and functionMap variables will be accessed by multiple thread.**

Comment: "new Java memory model" <-- link?

Comment: check this.
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly when ConcurrentHashMap should be used

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Function> functionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public Function getFunction(String key) {
        Function function = functionMap.get(key);
        if (function == null) {
            function = new Function(key);
            Function oldFunction = functionMap.putIfAbscent(function);
            if (oldFunction != null) {
                 function = oldFunction;
            }
        }
        return function;
}
```

Comment: i just had a brief look at the source of concurrentHashMap  
I assume it internally use some synchronization mechanisim to prevent JVM reordering so the function returns is guaranteed to be either fully constructed or a null?

Comment: the most important thing about putIfAbsent is that it atomically executes this logic: if (!map.contains(key)) {map.put(key, value); return null;) } else { return map.get(key);}

Answer (score 1):

@grumpynerd Hi, Your first assumption  is right about new Function(key) may be partially constructed after return of the method except if it is an immutable Object.

Your second assumption is wrong.

```
 this.functionMap = tempMap;

    // So here you will either see a null or a fully initialized map.
    // Is my understanding right?
    return this.functionMap;
```

now here you are writing and reading a same volatile variable next to next. And you assume that initializeMap will be completed before returns statement.
Your assumption hole True in Roach Motel Model. But its not necessarily true in JMM. as JMM is weaker model than Roach. See answer to the below question [Is this a better version of Double Check Locking without volatile and synchronization overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169145/is-this-a-better-version-of-double-check-locking-without-volatile-and-synchroniz)

**Updated from here as it cannot come in comment**.
Am sorry your second assumption also hold true. 
But keep in mind  this.functionMap = tempMap; may in practice behaves like all the statement
have been executed before it and been flush to the memory as it is explained by Doug lea cookbook
http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html this, but this is only a guide on how to implement JMM. For example look the code here 
[Is this a better version of Double Check Locking without volatile and synchronization overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169145/is-this-a-better-version-of-double-check-locking-without-volatile-and-synchroniz)

here i tried to use volatile fence as an memory barrier 
even if you make the statement

```
fence = true; 
fence = fence;
```

Now here i am doing volatile read and write, assuming that this will make my object 
fully initialized before returning the reference and hence if i again check 
that reference to be non-null then i am sure that the object will be fully initialized.
But the above reasoning is flawed because am trying to think in terms of memory barriers 
rather than the java happen-before guarantees. What is flawed in my question was that field reference was not volatile therefore any other thread is not reading any volatile reference. If its found field !- null even then it may read wrong values for the other instance fields of FieldType. As there is no guarantees by java when reading non-volatile values.

Therefore never thinks in terms of restricting ordering of statements. Always think 
what is guaranteed by JLS/JMM happens before relationship.

for example

int count = 1;
volatile boolean flag = true;

now jls state the above code will run in program order.
i.e count will be 1 first and then flag = true will  be executed.

```
    But Not the catch above from jls http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

        It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship 
between two actions does not necessarily imply that they 
have to take place in that order in an implementation. 
If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, 
it is not illegal.

        For example, the write of a default value to every 
field of an object constructed by a thread need not 
happen before the beginning of that thread, as long as no 
read ever observes that fact.
```

The above states that count = 1 may be executed after flag = true. if the execution is a legal execution. But our observations would be like that count=1 has been executed first. keyword is 
        observation. (It may happen here also if suppose compiler finds that flag 
    not shared among other threads then it might be legal .. this is just hyposthesis)

but now if in another thread executes the below statement then

```
    if(flag == true) {
       sysout(count) // count is  guaranteed  to be 1 
       // because of volatile guarantees flag will be only true if it has been set by first thread
       // and by program order count must have been set before flag has been set to  true.
       // therefore by program order i am printing count after reading value of a 
//volatile variable flag, therefore count must be 1.
    }
```

now if flag would have not been volatile then there is no happen-before relationship 
between the two threads. thread 2 very well could read flag == true and count as 0 as there 
are no observational guarantees  among threads.

In short guarantees are for observations and not how actually each statement executes.
read more about Program Order, Synchronization Order and Happens Before Order and lets share the knowledge :)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see why this is wrong, according to this link http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html
It says
In effect, because the new memory model places stricter constraints on reordering of volatile field accesses with other field accesses, volatile or not, **anything that was visible to thread A when it writes to volatile field f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f.**

Comment: So when Thread A execute this.functionMap = tempMap, it is guaranteed that whatever that is made visiable to this thread will be flushed to main memory so THread B will see the same thing right?

Comment: I did some additional search and I've also asked Doug Lea about my second assumption, so I think my second assumption is also correct. Please let me know if still think this is wrong perhaps provide me more details about why it is wrong? thanks

Comment: i have updated my comment in answer as it was too long for comment

Comment: Thanks veritas, for your research and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a variable `volatile` is useful only if the variable value change and is accessed by more than one thread. Your `functionMap` is a reference to the map and unless your want to assign a new Map instance to this reference, volatile here is useless. To be clear, volatile will not affect the Map content, only the Map *pointer*.

**I feel that you are think that Java method calls are asynchronous**, it is not. In your first example `new Function(key);` call will not return until the `Function` object is fully initialized.

Same thing for the second, unless that `initalizeMap` starts a new thread to do it's stuff, there is no problem here. And even in the case that `intializeMap` makes some asynchronous work, as you have `new HashMap<>()`, tempMap cannot be null, may be not fully loaded with the values added by initalizeMap (I repeat only if `initalizeMap` starts a new Thread) but no null.

Comment: I am talking about it in a multi thread context, in a single thread context, every call is appeared to be synchronous.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand my question or maybe I didn't make this clear, I am talking about these in a multi thread context, and these instance variables will get accessed by multiple thread at the same time

Comment: Yes, but either in a multi thread context, there is no asynchronous calls in your examples. Just only concurrent access that have to be handled with synchronization at `getFunction` and `getFunctionMap` methods.