# Is this a better version of Double Check Locking without volatile and synchronization overhead

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, volatile

Below code snippet is from Effective Java 2nd Edition Double Checked Locking

// Double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields

```
private volatile FieldType field;

FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) {  // First check (no locking)
        synchronized(this) {
            result = field;
            if (result == null)// Second check (with locking)  
                field = result = computeFieldValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

From what i know the main Problem with Double Checked Locking is the reordering inside second check locking so that the other  thread might see the values of field/result as set which may be infact still be in executing. To avoid this we make the reference of field as volatile to gurantee visibility and reordering.

But this can be achieved by the below code also

```
private FieldType field; // non volatile
private volatile boolean fence = false;

FieldType getField() {
    if (field == null) {  // First check (no locking) // no volatile read
        synchronized(this) {   //  inside synch block no problem of visibilty will latest           //value  of field 
            if (field == null) {// Second check (with locking)  
                Object obj =  computeFieldValue();
             fence = true; // any volatile write will take. this will make sure statements are //not reorder with setting field as non null.
            field = (FieldType)obj; // this will be only set after computeFieldValue has been //completed fully
           }
        }
    }
    return field;
}
```

So after when the initialization have been done, then no thread will have to for volatile read or synchronization overhead. Please 
see if my assumptions are right or not?

Comment: Isn't double checked locking considered a bad thing these days? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: There is one clear way to avoid this: refactor your code so as to _not_ require double check locking! In (100 - epsilon)% of cases this is doable, and what you should do anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve "cheap" double-checked locking in pure JMM; something got to give.

Your solution doesn't work because a volatile write can be reordered with a following normal action. See [jsr133 cookbook](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) for allowed reordering in the so called "roach motel" model. "Roach motel" is a stronger model than JMM, so if your solution fails in roach motel, it fails in JMM.

```
roach motel model
reordering between a normal action and a volatile/monitor action

   --                              <--
  |                                   |
  |    VolatileLoad / MonitorEnter    | forbidden
  |                                   |
   --> allowed                      --


   --> allowed                      --
  |                                   | 
  |    VolatileStore / MonitorExit    | forbidden
  |                                   |
   --                              <--
```

There is a way to deter reordering of two normal actions in "roach motel" model

```
(1) action#1
(2) volatile write
(3) volatile read
(4) action#4
```

(1) cannot be reordered with (2), and (4) cannot be reordered with (3), therefore (1) and (4) cannot be reordered.

However, be warned that "roach motel" model is a stronger model than JMM. You cannot be sure that a JVM conforms to roach motel model. For a concrete example

```
action#1
synchronized(new Object()){}
synchronized(new Object()){}
action#4
```

according to roach motel, action#1 and action#4 can't be reordered; however JVM can legitimately (allowed by JMM) remove the two sync block then reorder the remaining two actions.

Comment: can you provide any reference material where we can find more about JMM being weaker than roach motel model

Answer (score 9):

The [JLS (Section 17.4.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) states:

> *"A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) **happens-before** every subsequent read of that field."*

You are not *reading* the `fence` variable after it is updated, so there is no "happens-before" relationship between the thread that updates `fence` and any second thread.  That means that the second thread is not guaranteed to see the updates to the `field` variable made by the first thread.

In short, your "improved" code is a broken implementation of double-checked locking.

Comment: +1 A broken implementation of double-checked locking which is a broken construct.  :-)

Comment: @Gray - double-checked locking is a bad idea ... but it *can* be implemented correctly ... using Java 1.5 and later.

Comment: Sure but typically it is more complex than 2 checks.  :-)  Here's a good example of a way to get it working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17112561/179850

Comment: @StephenC i think volatile write will act as fence not as a memory barrier what volatile write here is guaranteeing is that  field = (FieldType)obj will not be reordered with statements before fence = true. within  the same thread. Other thread may see the stale values of field but after entering the syn block they will see the lates value

Comment: @veritas `synchronized` already prevents reording but `fence` can act as a memory barrier if it is employed correctly which Stephen C correctly points out it isn't

Comment: @veritas - Please do the analysis using the rules and terminology set out in the JLS Chapter 17.  If your belief about your version of the code is correct, you will be able to *prove* it.  (Note that the Java memory model is not defined in terms of memory barriers, reordering, etc.  Rather it is defined in terms of what is guaranteed to happen and what is not guaranteed to happen.  Memory barriers, etc are merely ways of implementing the memory model.  So reasoning based on volatiles being memory barriers is flawed.)

Comment: @StephenC thanks for clearing my doubts, i understand where i was getting wrong ..thanks once again

Comment: @StephenC, "second thread is not guaranteed to see the updates to the field variable made by the first thread", could you please explain why? The first thread unlocks after it sets the `field`, so `field` should be visible to other threads after that. Or do you mean it's not visible before we release the lock?

Comment: *"The first thread unlocks after it sets the field, **so field should be visible to other threads after that.** "*  That is not correct.  The second thread also needs to acquire the lock in order to guarantee that it sees the updated value of field.

Answer (score 0):

According to sources I trust, it seems to be a working and safe code. Write of a volatile variable must enforce the write of all other variables and can be reordered neither with volatile nor with normal assignments.